# vim doesn't terminate when terminal is forcefully closed

Tags: vim, vi

steps to replicate:

1. [Windows PC] SSH to machine as user using [putty](https://www.putty.org/)/[cmder](https://cmder.net/) (centos 7 VM)
2. [Linux VM] `vim def.txt` (as a user)
3. [Windows PC] kill the terminal program ([putty](https://www.putty.org/)/[cmder](https://cmder.net/)) using task manager
4. [Windows PC] ssh to machine as root using [putty](https://www.putty.org/)/[cmder](https://cmder.net/)
5. [Linux VM] `vim def.txt` (as a root)
6. [Linux VM] vim will ask because of existing swp file, choose edit anyway, make changes
7. [Linux VM] save then exit.
8. [Linux VM] check ps

The Vim process will then still show, not terminating properly. Help a confused person please? I want to avoid using `kill` if possible, so are there any other steps to avoid having this kind of issue
Vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 10 2014 06:55:55)

I will answer any questions that you might ask. Sorry for the poor formatting!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I was using SSH too. Sorry!

EDIT 2: I just clarified what I wanted to

Comment: Hello! I dont understand what makes you believe vim still runs after step 2. I suggest when you kill the terminal at step 2, vim is killed, so the swp file stays there. Is it the root/user way of starting vim? Maybe you could just check after step 2 if vim is still running? (in which case there is a mechanism that keeps it up like nohup or something).

Comment: @VincentAchard See the last step in the list. They can see the `vim` process in the `ps` output.

Comment: How did you kill the terminal program? Depending on that, it may or may not kill child processes.

Comment: what terminal program?

Comment: The process is supposed to be a child process of the shell, not the terminal. Are you killing the shell that started `vim`? And who is the owner of the `vim` running at (6)?

Comment: Why not use `ps` after step 2 to verify whether vim is still running or not? Why go to the bother of running vim again?

Comment: OK answering questions:
> How did you kill the terminal program? Depending on that, it may or may not kill child processes. – muru
    > I killed it by force closing the terminal program (cmder) on task manager as a way to simulate losing internet connection (a commonplace happening in my area)>

Comment: Who is the owner of the vim running at (6)? – Philippos > it's the user still.

Comment: Eh... if you losing internet connection is commonplace, you should be looking into using `screen` or `tmux`, not whether Vim is being killed or not.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/

Comment: Eh... if you losing internet connection is commonplace, you should be looking into using screen or tmux, not whether Vim is being killed or not. meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem – muru 


Isn't Cmder a similar implementation of it?

Comment: Why not use ps after step 2 to verify whether vim is still running or not? Why go to the bother of running vim again? -  wurtel 

> that's because we just assumed that Vi is still running, so we expect that when we open Vi we go back to the file being edited, and continue editing the file (as to not lose progress)

Comment: No, screen and tmux serve a different purpose. Also, please edit your question to consolidate all the information added in comments here.

Comment: I think Nxkai issue relates to this post http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=111454&p=888170#post888170 . He's trying to simulate the issue, that's why.

Comment: You should really use `ClientAliveCountMax` + `ClientAliveInterval` on the sshd server. Otherwise, the sshd server has no way to know if the connection was broken, unless the process(es) running on the server try to send something through it (a `vim` process expecting commands from the user isn't writing anything to the screen). I guess that putty/whatever has a mode where closing the window will not tear up the connection. This issue is not reproducible with a pseudo-tty in general -- when getting a `SIGHUP`, vim will terminate, no question asked.